# How to block shell script until new background image is set AND displayed?

Tags: shell-script, x11, wallpaper, feh

I ran this as a test to check if feh blocks util the background changes then exits/returns, turns out it doesn't (because only pic2 gets displayed as background, pic1 flashes for milliseconds sometimes before).

```
feh --bg-scale pic1.jpg && feh --bg-scale pic2.jpeg
```

is there an (x11?) event for background changed that can be triggered in bash? that can be a solution.

my goal is to show each pic exactly n seconds (using the sleep command) not more or less, which is currently dependent on how much time it takes for the pic to get scaled, set AND displayed as background.

my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
~/.scripts/helpers/killall-other-script-instances
while true
do
    for f in ~/Pictures/wallpapers/show/*; do
        feh --bg-scale $f
        sleep 3
    done
done
```

Comment: I'd bet that `feh` waits until the bg is set (which should be almost instant), but not until it is shown.

Comment: I untagged bash as it's not directly involved; it seems more along the lines of an X11 question.

Comment: @RoVo Yup, my test proved it, feh exited before I could see the background change, thus i'm asking this. probably I should edit "set as background" to "set and shown as background".
@ JeffSchaller sorry, I forgot to read the tag descriptions.

Comment: if the pictures take different amounts of time to scale, then your timings will be thrown off -- you'd have to keep track of when the last one finished rendering *and* know how long the next one will take to render.

Comment: that's what I though so, too. they're all different with a much higher res. than my monitor.  I will try pre-scaling them now to my monitors resolution with a single Image Magic command.